# Is remounting same file system with different options disruptive for current operations?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

I want to remount a file system with optimized options (noatime,nobarrier,etc.) on SLES11. I was going to do it by updating `/etc/fstab` first and then do something like `mount -o remount /srv/share`. The problem is that there are images of several active virtual machines on this file system exported via NFS and I was thinking if `remount` can be done without shutting them down. So is `remount` operation disruptive? Have anyone ever tried something like this before? What was the outcome?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just did something similar and it had no discernible effect on the remote host.  I say: go for it.

What I did:

- hostA (client) mounts hostB (server)
  via NFS: `mount hostB:/share /share`
- on hostA the following command was run: `( cd /bigdata && tar
  cf - . ) | ( cd /share && tar xvf - )`
- hostB the following command was run: `mount -o remount,noatime
  /share`

I saw no problems, no log messages.

Comment: It just worked for me too. There was a backup restore running on this volume as well as several active VMs doing data crunching at the same time. Thanks.