# Is it safe to remount to enable ACL?

Tags: centos, mount, access-control-list

I want to enable ACL on the server with CentOS. I get this error "operation not supported" while running `setfacl` command and I noticed that even there is ext4 with defaults options in fstab file that when I run: `tune2fs -l <partition>` I get: `Default mount options:    (none)`. So I want to add `acl` to /etc/fstab and run this command: `mount -o remount <file-system>`. I've run this command locally on my Ubuntu system and nothing has happened, but I need to run this on the server with which I'm connected via SSH and I'm worried if anything can break. What is the risk and is it safe to do that? (I can't just restart the server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/255716/is-remounting-same-file-system-with-different-options-disruptive-for-current-ope) remounting filesystem is not disruptive. I verified it several times myself and it never caused any issues.

Comment: thanks for your opinion. I've finally run that command to remount filesystem on the server and it seems to be working fine for all services.